# Image Size for Various Devices in Android?

Tags: android, layout

HI I am designing a Application for E-commerce and want to create icon for this application. I had read that there are number of Resolution are like

1. ldpi
2. mdpi
3. hdpi
4. xhdpi
5. xxhdpi

So what image size I should use for Application ? I am new in Android so let me know.

Comment: What kind of devices your are planning to target ?

Comment: My resolutions are 

480 X 800
720 X 1280

Comment: Go through this link

http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create different sizes of icons. Use some image editor to scale them.

`res/mipmap-mdpi/my_icon.png         // launcher icon for medium-density
res/mipmap-hdpi/my_icon.png         // launcher icon for high-density
res/mipmap-xhdpi/my_icon.png        // launcher icon for extra-high-density
res/mipmap-xxhdpi/my_icon.png       // launcher icon for extra-extra-high-density
res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/my_icon.png      // launcher icon for extra-extra-extra-high-density`

```
48 × 48 (mdpi)
72 × 72 (hdpi)
96 × 96 (xhdpi)
144 × 144 (xxhdpi)
192 × 192 (xxxhdpi)
512 × 512 (Google Play store)   .png
```

Pretty good guide here :
http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/

Comment: woooow thnxx brother,,, You are Awesome :-)

Comment: but let me ask you what is it exactly 48 X 48 ?

Comment: inch or centimetre or what ?